# Receiving message 'ruby-2.0.0-p647 is not installed' when switching to ruby project directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cygwin, rvm

Whenever I `cd` into my ruby project directory, I receive the following message:

```
$ cd millpool/
ruby-2.0.0-p647 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p647'
```

and when I `cd` back out, I receive:

```
$ cd ..
usage: 'rvm alias [action] [alias_name] [ruby_string]'
Regenerating ruby-2.0.0-p481 wrappers........
```

I have the following line in my project Gemfile:

```
ruby "2.0.0"
```

There is neither a `.rvmrc` or `.ruby-version` file in my project directory. The output of rvm list shows only one ruby version:

```
$ rvm list
rvm rubies
=* ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]
# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

So somewhere is a configuration telling rvm to use 2.0.0-p647 for the project in millpool/, but I can't find where that is. Noteworthy that this is within a cygwin instance. It was restored from a backup of the cygwin directory, which is when the issue appeared. The app still runs fine using 2.0.0p-481.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that `rvm` is trying to use the latest patch for 2.0.0, which used to be 481 but is now 647.

First, reasonably-recent versions of `rvm` know how to use a `ruby` directive from a `Gemfile`, as [documented here](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects). So even though there is no `.ruby-version`, `rvm` still knows you want Ruby 2.0.0.

Second, since the `Gemfile` doesn't specify a patch, `rvm` wants to use the most recent patch it's aware of, [documented here](https://rvm.io/rvm/basics).

So it sounds like you updated `rvm`'s master list of rubies, probably by saying `rvm get stable`, and now `rvm` treats `ruby '2.0.0'` as `-p647` instead of `-p481`.

Also: the messages you get from `cd ..` are because your default ruby is the fully-qualified `ruby-2.0.0-p481`, and once there is no more `Gemfile`, you go back to using your default.

Comment: Based on the doc you linked I had a look at `$rvm_path/config/db` and `$rvm_path/config/known` and changed ruby-2.0.0-p647 to ruby-2.0.0-p481 in each. This eliminated the `647 not installed` msg, but now I get the `regenerating wrappers` msg both when entering and exiting my project directory. since there is only one ruby 2.0.0 installed (and only one known now), this seems wierd.

Comment: If you're changing rvm's internal files I think all bets are off. It would be better to either install p647 and use it (good to be on the latest patch, and low-risk in this case), or change your Gemfile so it insists on p481, so that rvm knows that's what you want.

Comment: This shows how to ask for a specific patch: http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile_ruby.html (`ruby "2.0.0", patchlevel: 481`).

Comment: I tracked down the `Regenerating wrappers` message to a rvm hook (`.rvm/hooks/after_use_textmate`), and removed it. However as mentioned by Paul, I'm editing rvm files and might be breaking stuff. Paul's comment to either install p647 or change the gemfile to requre p481 is the proper solution.